VSCODE remote ssh editing cannot find my host
in terminal I do ssh user@home.lan or ssh user@192.168.8.186 and it works
in VSCODE I do the same in Connect to Host in the remote-ssh plugin and It does not work
error:
Could not establish connection to "home.lan": No route to host.
[15:07:21.999] Spawned 86635
[15:07:21.999] Using connect timeout of 17 seconds
[15:07:22.067] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 50575 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@home.lan
[15:07:22.068] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=86643
[15:07:22.072] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[15:07:22.075] stderr> ssh: connect to host home.lan port 22: No route to host
[15:07:22.076] > local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down
[15:07:22.077] Local server exit: 0
[15:07:22.077] Received install output: local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 50575 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@home.lan
local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=86643
OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
ssh: connect to host home.lan port 22: No route to host
local-server-1> ssh child died, shutting down


Looking at ssh -D option

ssh -v -T -D 50575 -o ConnectTimeout=15 user@home.lan

Seems like it's tunneling all traffic through the remote server on port 50575. You will need to add a firewall rule to allow traffic to port 50575 on your local machine.
Updated:

After macOS Sequoia update, we need to give Local Network access to VS
Code. Settings>Privacy & Security>Local Network and allow VS Code.

If you use MacOS please consider this.

.... no route to host
